# Permission denied on `git push` after transferring repo to new Github organization

Tags: git, github, github-organizations

I recently setup a public repo, built a simple app and everything worked as expected.

Eventually I decided the repo should live under a public organization to help encourage contributions. So I created a new organization then transferred the repo to the new organization. I'm setup as the owner (and only member) of this organization.

I then updated the `remote` on my local using:

```
git remote set-url [new org repo URL]
```

A `git remote -v` displays the new org repo URL.

I made a few more edits (to update the links to the repo in the README) and did a `git push origin master` to push the changes to the new repo.

And got:

```
remote: Permission to [new org repo URL] denied to [user].
fatal: unable to access 'https://[user]@[new org repo URL]': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

A `git pull origin master` returns successfully.

I have also tried:

- Changed the default permission for members of the org to both Write and Admin
- Deleted my local repo, then cloned from the new org repo URL, then tried pushing again
- Created a team under the new org, then added the repo to that team with Admin permissions

But still get the Permission Denied issue.

What other git, repo, and/or org permissions changes do I need to make?

Comment: did you add yourself or the team you are participating to collaborators/teams of the corresponding repository? If yes, what's the permission level you assigned to your profile/team for the corresponding repository?

Comment: @rufer7 Yes, I did try that. I've updated the question with those details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your project folder,

- Go to `.git` folder and edit the `config` file.
- find `url=`entry under section `[remote "origin"]`
- change the url to `ssh://git@[new org repo URL]`
- save config file and quit.

Now you can do `git push origin master` and it should work

EDIT

Using `ssh` is an alternative to `https`. You should have been asked for a GitHub username and password when you cloned your repo (assuming you used `https`). If you have enabled two-factor authentication, or if you are accessing an organization that uses SAML single sign-on, you must provide a personal access token instead of entering your password for HTTPS Git. This error can occur if you are using an old version of git.

Comment: Worked for me. Do you know why this change is required?

Comment: for SSH from command line try: `git remote set-url origin <paste the 'Clone with SSH' path>`  it worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Switching to an SSH URL is one workaround.
But regarding the HTTPS URL, do check:

- if your account has [2FA activated](https://help.github.com/articles/securing-your-account-with-two-factor-authentication-2fa/)
- if you have a Git credential helper check the returned value of git config credential.helper). If yes, [remove any GitHub entry](https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain/), and try a push again: that will prompt for your GitHub credentials (again, if you don't have 2FA).

Comment: I do have 2FA enabled, and it crossed my mind it, or another security measure, was the culprit.

Comment: @BrettDeWoody With 2FA, you need a PTA (Personal Access Token) as a pasword: https://github.com/settings/tokens