# git push command-line permission-denied error via HTTPS between local repo and organization github repo

Tags: github, terminal, permissions, repository, organization

I am an "owner" member of a github organization. I was away from github for years - unfortunately, the change to the key and token system happened during that window and I "missed the message". I still don't quite understand how it works, and this may be the issue.

I am on linux, trying to work with my git repositories via terminal commands.

What I can do is push and pull repositories from my own github account just fine (I set up the token correctly I guess, after tons of sweating)

What I cannot do is push changes to a repository from my organization to its github. I am an owner, I tried turning off the 3rd party apps restrictions (even though I'm not using a 3rd party app at all). I am trying this with a repo closed using https; as far as I'm aware, that's the only option available unless I pay for an enterprise account?

Any guidance is extremely appreciated - I found numerous threads searching this topic, but they all seem to be older, suggest ssh (again, don't think this is an option for a non-enterprise organization account, right? - e.g., [Permission denied on `git push` after transferring repo to new Github organization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48020748/permission-denied-on-git-push-after-transferring-repo-to-new-github-organizati) ), or are users having trouble pushing to their own repositories as opposed to an organization one.

cloned repo in terminal using https link from organization github

made changes, git add -A, git commit -m 'message', then git push and git push origin master. Neither of these push commands works. Error reads:
'emote: Permission to MAPLabgroup/QA.git denied to thackerybrown.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/MAPLabgroup/QA.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403'

thackerybrown is confirmed as owner on the MAPLabgroup organization
https path is correct
tried turning off Oauth / remove restrictions for 3rd party apps and this didn't work

Was expecting push success